# Cannot send an empty message form like {embeds:[embed]}

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wrote a new command when my bot ran on my pc and not a server.
While the bot ran on my pc the command worked very well, but after I put my bot into a server
the command stopped working and I always get an error message:
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

The code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const recon = require('reconlx');
const rpages = recon.ReactionPages
const moment = require('moment');
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = class HelpCommand extends BaseCommand {
    constructor() {
        super('help', 'moderation', []);
    }

    async run(client, message, args) {
        const y = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        const sayEmbed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`example`)
        const sayEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`example`)
        const sayEmbed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`example`)
        const sayEmbed5 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`example`)
        const sayEmbed4 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`example`)
        const sayEmbed6 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`example`)
            .setDescription("[A készítőm Weboldala](https://istvannemeth1245.wixsite.com/inde/)\n\n")

        try {
            await
                message.delete();
            const pages = [{ embed: sayEmbed1 }, { embed: sayEmbed2 }, { embed: sayEmbed3 }, { embed: sayEmbed4 }, { embed: sayEmbed5 }, { embed: sayEmbed6 }];
            const emojis = ['◀️', '▶️'];
            const textPageChange = true;
            rpages(message, pages, textPageChange, emojis);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            message.channel.send('Nem tudom ki írni az üzenetet');
        }
        const contetn = `\n[${y}] - ${message.author.username} használta a help parancsot. `;
        fs.appendFile('log.txt', contetn, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.err;
                return;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Full error message:

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
^
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/Lee-Goldway/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/Lee-Goldway/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/833629858210250813/messages',
code: 50006,
httpStatus: 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. Are you sure that this `reconlx` package is compatible with your `discord.js` version? It's always a good idea to post your discord.js version when you have a problem with libraries.

If you're using `reconlx` v1, you can see in [their old documentation](https://github.com/reconlx/reconlx-api/tree/v1#reactionpages) that in `ReactionPages` the second parameter takes an array of embeds. If you check the [source code](https://github.com/reconlx/reconlx-api/blob/v1/src/functions/embedpages.js#L28), you can see that it tries to send the first item of `pages` as an embed, like this: `message.channel.send({ embeds: [pages[0]] })`.

It means that with your code `embeds` is an array where the first item is an object that has an `embed` key with the `sayEmbed1` embed, while `discord.js` accepts an array of `MessageEmbed`s.

I would try to pass down an array of embeds like this:

```js
const pages = [
  sayEmbed1,
  sayEmbed2,
  sayEmbed3,
  sayEmbed4,
  sayEmbed5,
  sayEmbed6,
];
```

PS: `ki írni` is incorrect. When the verb particle precedes the verb, they are written as one word. So, it should be `kiírni`. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided, there appears to be no code that references "`{embeds:[embed]}`".
However, assuming the error is coming from this line:

```js
message.channel.send('Nem tudom ki írni az üzenetet');
```

Referring to the [official documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), you can provide an object.

For example:

```js
message.channel.send({ content: 'Nem tudom ki írni az üzenetet' });
```

Comment: This slice of code is correct and works well. But this code is the real problem: ```try {
            await
                message.delete();
            const pages = [{ embed: sayEmbed1 }, { embed: sayEmbed2 }, { embed: sayEmbed3 }, { embed: sayEmbed4 }, { embed: sayEmbed5 }, { embed: sayEmbed6 }];
            const emojis = ['◀️', '▶️'];
            const textPageChange = true;
            rpages(message, pages, textPageChange, emojis);

        }
```

I think this is correct but when i want to run this command I get an error: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message